# Jsp not compilee when i placed in separate folder

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

My directory structure is

```
 Project
    -- src
    -- WEB-INF
          -- folder1  --> some jsp's
          -- folder2  --> some jsp's
          --folder3   --> some jsp's
          login.jsp
          logout.jsp
```

Only login.jsp gets loaded and the remaing pages under separate folder not compiled.
i have mentioned url-pattern as /folder1/jspfilename in web.xml file.
Still it is not compiling.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Those who voted negative please provide the answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Tomcat only compiles JSPs when they are requested.

Comment: //jeroen but i am getting the exception org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.tiles.xxx.header_jsp

Comment: @Shriram, this is not of your JSPs but a Tiles component. Seems you need to include the Apache Tiles library to your build path.

Comment: i am not facing any lib related issues. The problem is all the jsp's placed under the subfolder inside WEB-INF not getting compiled. I have cross verified in web.xml also.

Comment: @Shriram you will need to provide a lot more information then if you want to get help. Try to reduce your web application to the utmost minimal configuration that will still raise the errors and then post your JSP files, web.xml and folder structure here.